# Vue/Inertia.js not updating value in database

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have the below form:

```html
<form @change="updatePipeline">
  <select v-model="pipeline.input_mode">
     <option value="text">Text</option>
     <option value="html">HTML</option>
     <option value="json">JSON</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The `@change` is calling the below:

```js
<script setup>
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
const props = defineProps({
    pipeline: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
});

const form = useForm({
    input_mode: props.pipeline.input_mode,
});

const updatePipeline = () => {
    form.put(route('pipelines.update', props.pipeline), {
        errorBag: 'updatePipeline',
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
};
```

The value is not updated in the database:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Pipeline $pipeline)
{
    $pipeline->update(
        $request->validate([
            'input_mode' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        ])
    );


    return redirect()
        ->route('pipelines.edit', ['pipeline' => $pipeline])
        ->with('success', 'Pipeline edited successfully.');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured this out shortly after asking the question here. The reason why the database is not being persisted, is that I am referring `pipeline` on the `v-model` property. Instead, I should refer to `form`:

```html
<form @change="updatePipeline">
  <select v-model="form.input_mode">
     <option value="text">Text</option>
     <option value="html">HTML</option>
     <option value="json">JSON</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

So, instead of having: `v-model="pipeline.input_mode"`, I have: `v-model="form.input_mode"`.

Answer (score 0):

### PAY ATTENTION TO THE FIRST COMMENT ON THIS ANSWER. IT DEPENDS ON THE VERSION

I'm not an expert in inertia but when you do

```php
$pipeline->update(
        $request->validate([
            'input_mode' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        ])
    );
```

it returns a `void` as you can see here https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_validate

What you are looking for is:

```php
$request->validate(['input_mode' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255'])

$pipeline->update($request->validated());
```

`validated()` will return an array of items that were validated.

---

### EDIT

Do you have the `input_mode` in the `$fillables` in your modal `Pipeline`? If not, that's your problem

```php
protected $fillables = ['input_mode'];
```

Comment: Oh wait. I sent docs for `5.5` and not `9.x` version. In the `9.x` version it actually returns the data https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Validator.html#method_validate